# Kotlin: Can I force Not Nullable Long to be represented as non primitive type in JVM?

Tags: java, kotlin, primitive-types

From kotlin docs:

> Long ... Represents a 64-bit signed integer. On the JVM, non-nullable values of
>   this type are represented as values of the primitive type long.

But it causes issue in my spring boot application when send json request without `postId` in the body and when I need to apply jsr 303 validation to my kotlin class, like this:

```
data class Comment(
   @field:NotNull
   val postId: Long,
   ...
)
```

So issue is that Comment class is constructed with postId = 0 automatically and validation is not failing.

Is there a way to force kotlin's Long type to be represented as non primitive type in JVM? (may be with help of annotations or compiler arguments, etc)?

P.S.: I can force it by making postId of type Long?, but I don't like it (First of all, it should not be nullable, second, then I need to use `comment.postId!!`, which is ugly and it brakes advantage of kotlin's null safety).

Comment: What's the point of validating that a non-nullable property is not null? OTOH if your `Comment` is going to be instantiated with data where `postId` _may_ be null, then you have no choice but using a nullable type to represent this.

Comment: When you send json request without postId, the class is constructed successfully and 0 is used as a value of postId automatically. But the construction of this class should fail, because postId is not provided actually.

Comment: Yes, so in reality `postId` is a property that _may_ be null. You have to represent this in the static type. Maybe you can have a raw data class that represents the JSON input and another one that represents it after it has passed validation.

Comment: what about using `java.lang.Long`?

Comment: @Teimuraz I’d say this maybe a bug with the Kotlin Jackson module. The module should be able to fail constructing this object (but your validation will never even be triggered mind you, because you’re using a non nullable type).

Comment: @asm0dey I thought about it, but feels hacky, don't want to mix it in my kotlin code

Comment: @Teimuraz well you can't pretend that nullable type is not nullable and vise versa. But inability to create primitive long looks as unexpected behaviour for me. Meanwhile sometimes you need java.lang things, ie for syncronization

Comment: Synchronizing on a `java.lang.Long` would be very bad practice, though, even if in a `final` field. It's a dark corner of early Java design that you can synchronize on any object.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to avoid that. You need to configure the parser, in this case Jackson, to not have default values to primitives types. As in this post here [Jackson deserialization of missing JSON number value to 0.0 in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73123790/jackson-deserialization-of-missing-json-number-value-to-0-0-in-spring)

```
@Configuration
class JacksonConfig {
    @Bean
    fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
        return jacksonObjectMapper()
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES, true)
    }
}
```

or

```
 spring:
  jackson:
    deserialization:
      FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue, and IDEA offer that solution, to create Long as type object
Use declaration like:

`var postId by Delegates.notNull<Long>()`