# Jackson deserialization of missing JSON number value to 0.0 in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson-databind

I have defined a Kotlin data class like this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class MandatoryLimits(

  val upper: Double,

  val lower: Double

)
```

as part of a compound object that my Spring service receives as a request body in a POST request. When I send a test request with one value missing, e.g. like this:

```
           "specificationLimits": {
                "lower": 1.6
            }
```

then I receive a correctly deserialised object of Type MandatoryLimits, but the missing value is set to simply 0.0.

I would have expected to get a BAD REQUEST from the service, instead. Do I need to configure something in addition?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fail deserialization when a Kotlin primitive is null, you need to make sure the `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES` Jackson configuration flag is active.

Below is an example of `ObjectMapper` bean configuration that will throw an error when it tries deserializing a `null` Kotlin primitive.

```
@Configuration
class JacksonConfig {
    @Bean
    fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
        return jacksonObjectMapper()
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES, true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Anything else special needed to get this changed picked up, because I added the configuration in the class path and I am still not getting the correct behavior?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I defined the data class members as nullable and added an init Block to validate the presence of both values. In case of an error, I throw the response exception manually.